# Unique combinations of length 2 of two strings using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a small function that prints out the combinations:

```
def get_data(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) == 0 or len(str2) == 0:
        return
    print str1[0], str2[0]
    get_data(str1[1:], str2)
    get_data(str1, str2[1:])


get_data("stu", "wxyz")
```

I get the output as:

```
s w
t w
u w
u x
u y
u z
t x
u x
u y
u z
t y
u y
u z
t z
u z
s x
t x
u x
u y
u z
t y
u y
u z
t z
u z
s y
t y
u y
u z
t z
u z
s z
t z
u z
```

The output has a lot of repeated pairs. How can I get only unique values?

Comment: I suspect this is merely an exercise. But if not, be sure to check out `product`:
`from itertools import product`. Then: 
`list(product("stu", "wxyz"))` gives
`[('s', 'w'), ('s', 'x'), ('s', 'y'), ('s', 'z'), ('t', 'w'), ('t', 'x'), ('t', 'y'), ('t', 'z'), ('u', 'w'), ('u', 'x'), ('u', 'y'), ('u', 'z')]`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with a simple for loop?

```
def get_data(str1, str2):
    for char in str1:
        for char2 in str2:
            print char, char2


get_data("stu", "wxyz")
```

output:

```
s w
s x
s y
s z
t w
t x
t y
t z
u w
u x
u y
u z
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is complicated, uses recursion which is slower and more memory-intensive than loops, and as you noted doesn't quite work correctly.

Here is an easier version using loops. Uniqueness is obvious, at least if no character is repeated in either string. This also works well for other data types, such as two lists.

```
def getdata(str1, str2):
    for s1 in str1:
        for s2 in str2:
            print(s1, s2)

getdata("stu", "wxyz")
```

This prints what you want:

```
s w
s x
s y
s z
t w
t x
t y
t z
u w
u x
u y
u z
```

Note that my code is for Python 3: to use it in Python 2 just remove the surrounding parentheses in the `print` statement, or import **print** from future.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on recursion:

```
def get_data(s1,s2):
    get_data_helper( s1, s2, s2 )

def get_data_helper(s1,s2,s2full):
'''Print all combinations of s1[0] w/ s2, followed by all combinations from s1[1:] with s2full
   s2 is a suffix of s2full'''
    if s1=="":
        return
    if s2=="":
        get_data_helper( s1[1:],s2full,s2full)
    else:
        print s1[0], s2[0]
        get_data_helper( s1, s2[1:], s2full )
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has lovely tools for various iterations, in the package **itertools**.  The one you need here is **product**, the cartesian product of a set of iterable items.

I added a **join**-with-space operation to get the output in your original format.  You can also just use the ordered pair of characters.

```
import itertools
def get_data(str1, str2):
    for combo in itertools.product(str1, str2):
        print ' '.join(combo)

get_data("stu", "wxyz")
```

Output:

```
s w
s x
s y
s z
t w
t x
t y
t z
u w
u x
u y
u z
```